# Solving a system of two equations of cube integers using ParallelTable

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

Well, I have the following problem: I need to solve the following system of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
n=a^3+b^3+c^3\\
\\
n=d^3+k^3+f^3
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Where:

- $n\ne a\ne b\ne c\ne d\ne k\ne f$;
- $1\le a<n,1\le b<n,1\le c<n,1\le d<n,1\le k<n,1\le f<n$;
- $n\in\mathbb{N}^+,a\in\mathbb{N}^+,b\in\mathbb{N}^+,c\in\mathbb{N}^+,d\in\mathbb{N}^+,k\in\mathbb{N}^+,f\in\mathbb{N}^+$

And I want to search for solutions using the following range: $2\le n\le1000^3$.

I thought of the following code:

```
ParallelTable[{n,Solve[{n==a^3+b^3+c^3,n==d^3+k^3+f^3,
1<=a<n&&1<=b<n&&1<=c<n&&1<=d<n&&1<=k<n&&1<=f<n&&a!=b!=c!=d!=k!=f},
{a,b,c,d,k,f},Integers]},{n,2,1000^3}]
```

> Question: is there a faster way to let Mathematica evaluate this?

---

**EDIT:**

After seeing the answer that was posted by @kglr, I wondered can I use that technique to solve the same problem by using more variables:

$$
\begin{cases}
n=a^3+b^3+c^3\\
\\
n=d^3+k^3+f^3\\
\\
n=g^3+h^3+m^3\\
\\
n=a^3+k^3+m^3\\
\\
n=g^3+k^3+c^3\\
\\
n=a^3+d^3+g^3\\
\\
n=b^3+k^3+h^3\\
\\
n=c^3+f^3+m^3
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

All the conditions are the same, so they all can not be equal to each other and needs to be an integer bigger than zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1] 
While[Length[pr] < 2, 
  pr = Select[FreeQ @ 0] @ PowersRepresentations[RandomInteger[{2, 10^6}], 3, 3]]; //
     AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 5.8*10^-6
> ```

```
 {{a, b, c}, {d, k, f}, n} = Join[pr[[;;2]], {Total[pr[[1]]^3]}]
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 16}, {3, 9, 15}, 4131}
> ```

```
Total[pr^3, {2}]
```

> ```
> {4131, 4131}
> ```

If you want the 6 numbers all distinct:

```
SeedRandom[1]
While[Length[Union @@ pr] < 6, 
    pr = Select[FreeQ@0]@
      PowersRepresentations[RandomInteger[{2, 10^6}], 3, 3]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.0000275
> ```

```
pr
```

> ```
>  {{5, 53, 88}, {12, 29, 93}, {15, 74, 75}}
> ```

```
Total[pr[[1]]^3]
```

> ```
> 830474
> ```

Comment: @Jan, hope the new version makes it  easier to see the steps: We pick a random integer in the interval `2` to `20^6` (`RandomInteger[{2, 10^6}]`), find its  representations as the sum of 3 cubes (`PowersRepresentations[..., 3,3]`), select the triples free of `0` (`Select[FreeQ @0]`) , we repeat as long as the length of  triples we get is less than 2  (`Lenth[pr]<2`) .

Comment: First of all, I am very thankful for your time and answer, so +1. I understand your code. Can you help me with the problem I edited into my question, using your technique? Because that is the full problem I would like to solve.

Comment: @Jan, it is unlikely that we can find 5 sets of distinct triples in `Range[2, 10^6]` , that is, we probably end up with an infinite while loop if we use  random search without eliminating previously seen points.

Comment: some variables are used twice, so it is not really 5 sets of distinct triples. For example the variable $a$ turns up in the first and 4th equation. So maybe extend the range or something. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I also made a mistake, it should be 8 equations which are interlinked with each other.